# Svelte with a Component iterating over an array of Objects - Error: {#each} only iterates over array-like objects

Tags: loops, object, svelte

Loving and Still learning Svelte by testing stuff. I have created a Component containing an Image (on the right) and an Article (on the left) ; the article section includes a header, a paragraph and button-like anchor(s) (it can be one or more according to the needs of the article) - that can be personalized (thanks to exported props).

As you will see below, I created *buttonList* = an array of objects (these being derived from a class *ButtonModel*), *ButtonModel[]* and iterate over it to show as many button-like anchors as needed (each with its *href* and its *label*):

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { Icon } from '@mylib/ui';
  class ButtonModel {
    href: string;
    label: string;
    constructor(href: string, label: string) {
      this.href = href;
      this.label = label;
    }
  }
  export let imgSrc: string;
  export let alt: string;
  export let articleTitle: string;
  export let articleContent: string;
  export let buttonList: ButtonModel[];
</script>

<div class="imagearticle">
  <img class="imagearticle__image" src={imgSrc} {alt} />
  <article class="imagearticle__article">
    <h1>{articleTitle}</h1>
    <p>{articleContent}</p>
    <div class="imagearticle__article__buttonGroup">
      {#each buttonList as buttonModel}
        <a class="button" href={buttonModel.href} role="button">
          <Icon name="chevron-right" />
          {buttonModel.label}
        </a>
      {/each}
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

When I use it in a page, it is correctly rendered in the browser:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { _ } from 'svelte-i18n';
  import ArticleImage from '../lib/ImageArticle.svelte';
</script>

<main>
  <ArticleImage
    imgSrc="/images/forest.png"
    alt="Forest of cypress trees"
    articleTitle={$_('homepage.respect.title')}
    articleContent={$_('homepage.respect.p')}
    buttonList={[{ href: '/', label: $_('homepage.respect.btn') }]}
  />

  <ArticleImage
    imgSrc="/images/pairprogramming.png"
    alt="Two people pair programming in a shop"
    articleTitle={$_('homepage.inclusive.title')}
    articleContent={$_('homepage.inclusive.p')}
    buttonList={[
      { href: '/', label: $_('homepage.inclusive.btn') },
      { href: '/', label: $_('homepage.inclusive.contact') }
    ]}
  />
</main>
```

But when I run my test with Jest, I keep having the error message :
{#each} only iterates over array-like objects.

1. Could you help me understand this error (when looping over an array of Objects] ?
2. Any clues how to improve myself ? or the above code ?

Thanks

Comment: What if you give it a default value `export let buttonList: ButtonModel[] = [];`?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Corrl ! It worked ! But how come it is necessary to add a default value ? Shouldn't the TS expression ButtonModel[] be enough ?

Comment: Hm I don't see why it should, because it's only defining the type of and not the value itselft? If an exported prop is not passed via the parent the value inside the component will fall back to the default and there you didn't set one so it will be undefined, which can't be iterated. (If/when this could happen with Jest even though you might have passed a value, I can't tell)

Comment: Alright! It's way clearer now ! Thanks a lot